# Use a model instance in different controller - Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

There is a `HomeController` in `app/Http/Controllers` and a `Player` model in `app`.

HomeController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

Player:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
```

Double-checked, the Player model gets PSR-4 autoloaded. I've tried to `use` various versions in HomeController, but it keeps trying to look for Eloquent class (which Player extends) in wrong paths. Also, in the tested HomeController method, instantiating the model is foggy, do I need to prefix the namespace now? because with or without `use` command it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized that I had to alias this path to Eloquent to make it work:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
```

Comment: Some dev versions of Lara 5 have it already aliased in app/config/app.php, but this one didn't.

Comment: I'm used to deleting the question if the answer pops up just after posting it, but this might help others when 5 gets released. FYI one can't accept their answer in 48 hours.